# Converting c# project with a database (SQL Server Management Studio) into an exe file

Tags: c#, ssms

How to convert c# project with a database (SQL Server Management Studio) into an exe file?

Comment: What should happen when you run the exe?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do? This question is way too vague.

Comment: I just want to know what can I do to deploy my c# project with the database itself because I'm using SQL Server Management Studio software for my database. @ChrisPietschmann

Comment: When I run the exe my program should still add edit delete from my database. And I'm having a problem deploying it with the database. @adrianm

Answer (score 0):

1. SQL Server Management Studio isn't a database
2. You cannot include a MS SQL DB file inside an EXE
3. You cannot run a MS SQL DB without the Server application installed (SQL Server, or SQL Server Express)
4. You don't have a DB inside your EXE ever.

There are local DBs you can ship as part of the software like Access, SQLLite, etc, but they are separate files, and not part of your compiled executable.

Comment: oh i get it, but what advice can you give on how to link the SQL Server Management studio to my exe file? @Tim

Comment: Add an application config file and save the connection string to the database in there